# Is there a library/module for CodeIgniter for Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, codeigniter

Ideally something I can plug and play pretty readily an quickly that supports GeoCoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [Google Maps](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Google_Maps/) on the CI Wiki?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my own Google Maps API library a couple of weeks ago for CodeIgniter. You can download it and read the documentation [here](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library).

Although probably a little less functionality than the one on the CI Wiki, it still does everything I need it to and supports geocoding etc. Maybe I'll carry on developing it one day.